# chmod only files in current directory but not subdirectories and main directory

Tags: linux, bash, find, chown

I am trying to write a small bash script where I will change file permissions in batch and I can't figure out how to change permissions only on files in current directory and leave directory it self intact and subdirectories with different permission.

A few examples I tried are not working and I either end up changing recursively or changing main directory also.

This is the structure:

```
/dir/main_folder/
/dir/main_folder/subfolder1
/dir/main_folder/subfolder2
/dir/main_folder/subfolder3
/dir/main_folder/file1.php
/dir/main_folder/file2.php
/dir/main_folder/file3.php
```

So I would like to chmod all files under `main_folder` but leave `main_folder` permissions intact and also any folders under `main_folder` and files under those subfolders intact. The `subfolder1` and files inside that folder should be intact.

The find command like this: `find /opt/lampp/htdocs -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \;`  will change all files in subfolders too

Comment: I think `find` has an option to limit the number of levels

Comment: Try `-maxdepth 1`

Comment: Can you use zsh instead of bash? Just `chmod 0644 /dir/main_folder/*(.)` if so. See https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Glob-Qualifiers for details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `-type` and `-maxdepth` options to `find`, for example:

```
find * -maxdepth 0 -type f
```

This will find all non-dotfile files in the current directory (it will *exclude* files that begin with `.` because they don't match the glob expression `*`). If you want all files, you could use:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f
```

And if you don't want "the current directory", you can pass a directory path:

```
find /dir/main_folder/* -maxdepth 0 -type f
find /dir/main_folder -maxdepth 1 -type f
```

All of the above commands will print only *files* because of the `-type f` option.

Comment: I was not aware of `maxdepth` option for `find` this could work.